# Can't run rails server in windows 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, rubygems

**I want to start ruby server.**

I install:

```
gem install bundler

gem install sqlite3

gem install webpacker

gem install rails
```

And I create a new rails application.

```
gem new test_app
```

Also it's time to run server:

```
cd test_app

rails server
```

**But I take error shown below**

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.3 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:159:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:156:in `create_default_data_source'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `get'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
```

And similar mistakes

Comment: "tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)"—well, have you done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this gem to your gemfile.rb

gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

Comment: I already have this file. But nothing happaned :(

Comment: Perhaps your version of Windows is not being caught by that platforms restriction?

You could temporarily remove the platforms part of the line like so:

`gem "tzinfo-data"`

Then run `bundle install` again.

I'm not entirely sure if there's any negative impact from doing that.

Comment: I add gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2022', '>= 1.2022.1' and it's working. Thank you for help.